# Why SymmetricDS Server runnning false

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, symmetricds

I have installed SymmetricDS and started by running bin/sym_service start but when I check the status it shows the **server running is false**. What is happening here?

Comment: Check the output in wrapper.log for error conditions.